# What problems may occur while querying SQL databases with big amount of data over internet

Tags: sql, sql-server, solr, dataimporthandler

I am having this big database on one MSSQL server that contains data indexed by a web crawler. 
Every day I want to update SOLR SearchEngine Index using DataImportHandler which is situated in another server and another network.

Solr DataImportHandler uses query to get data from SQL. For example this query

```
SELECT * FROM DB.Table WHERE DateModified > Config.LastUpdateDate
```

The ImportHandler does 8 selects of this types. Each select will get arround 1000 rows from database.

To connect to SQL SERVER i am using *com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver*

The parameters I can add for connection are:

- responseBuffering="adaptive/all"
- batchSize="integer"

So my question is:

**What can go wrong while doing this queries every day ?**  ( except network errors )
I want to know how is SQL Server working in this context ?

Further more I have to take a decicion regarding the way I will implement this importing and how to handle errors, but first I need to know what errors can arise.

Thanks!

**Later edit**

My problem is that I don't know how can this SQL Queries fail. When i am calling this importer every day it does 10 queries to the database. If 5th query fails I have to options:
rollback the entire transaction and do it again, or commit the data I got from the first 4 queries and redo somehow the queries 5 to 10. But if this queries always fails, because of some other problems, I need to think another way to import this data.

Can this sql queries over internet fail because of timeout operations or something like this?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you give more context? As it is now, it's not very different from "what can go wrong while programming a computer?"

Comment: I agree with Mauricio a lot could go wrong. Though I would say 1000 rows is very small. I would make sure you have a index on the DataModified field and don't use * write out the query columns you need only.

Comment: I clarified a little bit the question. So, it is possible to do the queries like this and not have very big problems ?

Comment: the only problems that you can have is an error on you network or a timeout if the query take too long to execute. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem i identified after working with this type of import is:

- Network problem - If the network connection fails: in this case SOLR is rolling back any changes and the commit doesn't take place. In my program I identify this as an error and don't log the changes in the database.

Thanks @GuidEmpty for providing his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203188/what-problems-may-occur-while-querying-sql-databases-with-big-amount-of-data-ove#comment9474756_7203188) and clarifying  out this for me.

Answer (score -1):

There could be issues with permissions (not sure if you control these).

Might be a good idea to catch exceptions you can think of and include a catch all (Exception exp).

Then take the overall one as a worst case and roll-back (where you can) and log the exception to include later on.

You don't say what types you are selecting either, keep in mind text/blob can take a lot more space and could cause issues internally if you buffer any data etc.

Though just a quick re-read and you don't need to roll-back if you are only selecting.

I think you would be better having a think about what you are hoping to achieve and whether knowing all possible problems will help?

HTH